# Application for auto-scaling backgrounds in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, desktop-customization

One thing that's always annoyed me about Windows XP is how there's no "scale" option for the desktop background. It either has to be stretched or centered. It's a pretty simple algorithm to scale the image so that one of the dimensions (usually height) fits on the screen.

Does anyone know of a good program that does this, or is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

Any image processing or paint application will be able to do this. There's lots to choose from:

[Paint.NET](http://getpaint.net)

[Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/)

[Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/)

To name but three.

Comment: true, but I'm looking for something automatic.

Comment: Although irfanview has a fairly automatic process. "Set as desktop background" -> "scretched (proportional)" seems to do what I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

**[Wallmaster](http://www.wallmasterpro.com/wallmast.html)** seems to have options to do this (amongst other functions like changing automatically background, etc.)

[image: wallmaster screenshot]

I haven't tried it though, so I can't guarantee it actually does what you need.